# Phone config prob in 13.04!

Tags: 13.04, configuration, phone, nokia

I've recently installed Ubuntu and it's perfect, but when i **connnect my phone** via a usb cable to my ubuntu laptop below shown **error message pops up**. Tell me How can I fix it.

At least my folder also opens but I have an 5.9 GB memory in the card and the folder shows just this Cities folder. Also I can't paste anything to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt, try:
sudo nautilus

after typing your password, you should have super user authority to paste files.
Let us know if this works.